# Empty cell values in CSV files

Tags: excel, csv

Generally when I open CSV file with Notepad it looks like this

```
    DN3074;29.06.15;;;;AX103;;11,000;
```

But now I have CSV file that looks like this:

```
    "DN3074";"29.06.15";"";"";"";"AX103";"";"11,000"
```

I have to import the file in a third party software that is ok with `;"XXX";` (double quotes with data) but can't handle `;"";` (double quotes without data).

If I open and save the file on my PC with Excel then the empty double quotes disappear (transformed from `;"";` into `;;`) and I can't figure the setting that controls that process. I don't know if the file is generated through another software package or directly in Excel.

Is there a setting (Excel, Regional, etc) that handles how empty cells are interpreted in CSV file?

Comment: It looks like you did not respond when answers were posted to this question, but are now asking fresh questions. I think it is fair for helpers to expect some sort of reply, so do please get back to people, even if it is merely to upvote/accept answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I guess is to open file in Notepad and use Ctrl+H to replace `"` with empty spaces, or to replace only `""` with empty spaces. However, I am sure you are currently doing that.

Coming to the query, I've Excel 2010, where this `"` issue is not there. Below is a CSV sample file created on Excel, opened on Notepad:

```
1,45,0.626989589,0.988300859,0.427088077,0.537229165,,0.936975164
2,,0.993964647,0.419158727,0.697422199,,0.995851771,0.65717588
3,4324,0.705512764,,0.739675815,0.584418421,0.901237641,0.186385618
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fail, then try looking at the VBA sample here: http://markinns.com/archive/export-excel-csvs-with-double-quotes.html

If might need to be modified to exclude adding quotes on empty cells, but at least you have some VBA code to change as you please.